# meta_query compare LIKE doesn't show items when empty

Tags: wordpress, loops, filter, taxonomy

I have a loop that I am building a filter for, using a custom taxonomy.

It works, but only when there is a value entered. When the page loads it shows no entries, but when I filter by a value it shows the items with that tag. I thought that 'LIKE' would allow it show all entries while the value is empty.

I have tried this by removing the $ingredients and replacing it with an empty ''.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'ingredients',
                'value' => $ingredients,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>

        <?php the_title(); ?><br />

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check by passing false to the argument,

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'ingredients',
                'value' => $ingredients,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                   'key' => 'ingredients',
                   'value' => false,
                   'type' => 'BOOLEAN'
                ),
            )
        );
```

Also add compare => like to the false condition and cross check.